# parse values from @message field which contains plain text : AWS Cloudwatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

```
**@message  
{ "level": "INFO", "message": "User 2c5e2225-0037-4a0f-b87a-405d8b4f8fe8 has successfully downloaded the file IT_1994_December_ConditionSets_CardioSets,release 1994_December and file type .xlsx" }**
```

I want to extract value for User : 2c5e2225-0037-4a0f-b87a-405d8b4f8fe8, fileName : IT_1994_December_ConditionSets_CardioSets, fileType : .xlsx from above log.

Complexity here is that message field doesn't have key: value format data instead it has plain text.

Can someone help me to form query to extract data from message and display as alias in cloudwatch search result.

I have created regex to extract these values and tested it online. regex patters :

```
To extract User : /(?<=User\s).*(?=\shas)/ 
To extract filename : /(?<=file\s).+(?=,)/ 
To extract file type : /(?<=type\s).+(?=")/
```

I have created below query to parse and return data :

```
 fields user, fileName, fileType
  | filter @message like /downloaded/
  | parse @message /(?<user>^(?<=User\s).*(?=\shas))/
  | parse @message /(?<fileName>^(?<=file\s).+(?=,))/
  | parse @message /(?<fileType>^(?<=type\s).+(?="))/
```

It is not returning the result as expected. can anyone please review this query if any improvement needed in that ??

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the expected result you want?

Comment: Hi @Omar, I have updated post with all the additional details. Can you please go through it and provide your input.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to form correct query to extract values from plain text by parsing message using regex.

Final working query is  :

```
fields @user, @fileName, @fileType
| filter @message like /downloaded/
| parse @message /(?<@user>(?<=User\s).*(?=\shas))/
| parse @message /(?<@fileName>(?<=file\s).+(?=,))/
| parse @message /(?<@fileType>(?<=type\s).+(?="))/
```

I made some syntax corrections and it started returning expected results.

Comment: The key for me was that the non captured group, (the bit of the regex not in brackets) is assigned to the variable.